# Why is $\lim_{t\to 0}W(t)=0$ equivalent to $\forall n\ge 1 \; \exists m\ge 1\; \forall r\in \mathbb{Q}\cap (0,\frac{1}{m}]:|W(r)|\le \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, probability-theory, brownian-motion

Let $t \mapsto W_t, t>0$ be continuous. We want to show that $\lim_{t\downarrow 0}W(t)=W(0)=0.$ $W$ here is actually the reflected Brownian motion $tB(1/t)$. It says in the text that the limit $\lim_{t\to 0}W(t,w)=0$ if, and only if, 
$$\forall n\ge 1 \; \exists m\ge 1\; \forall r\in \mathbb{Q}\cap (0,\frac{1}{m}]:|W(r)|=|rB(\frac{1}{r})|\le \frac{1}{n}.$$

I'm not sure why we only need to consider rational points here. What we want to show is that $\forall \epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|t|<\delta$ then $|W(t)|<\epsilon$. But how is this a consequence, or equivalent to the above statement? I tried showing this as follows:

We can choose $n$ such that $1/n<\epsilon$, and $\delta<1/m$. Then we want to show that $|W(t)|<\epsilon$ for $|t|<\delta$, so we can use triangle inequality $|W(t)|\le |W(r)|+|W(t)-W(r)|$. However, since we don't have uniform continuity, I can't bound $|W(t)-W(r)|$ uniformly in this interval $(0,\delta)$ so that $\delta$ does not depend on the specific $t$. How can I prove this? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: As $W$ is continuous, $\sup_{x\in (0,\frac1m]}|W(x)|=\sup_{x\in (0,\frac1m]\cap\Bbb Q}|W(x)|$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen why are they the same? And why must they be bounded? Also how do we use this to prove the above result?

Comment: For the record, the question in the title is not probabilistic in the least and is only concerned with the notion of continuity of real valued functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Lemma** Let $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a 1-dimensional Brownian motion. Then $$\mathbb{P} \left( \limsup_{t \to \infty} \left| \frac{B_t}{t} \right |\leq R \right) = 1$$ for any $R>0$.

*Proof:* By Doob's maximal inequality, we have

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{n \leq t \leq n+1} \left| \frac{B_t}{t} \right| \geq R \right) &\leq \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{n \leq t \leq n+1} |B_t|^4 \geq n^4 R^4 \right) \\ &\leq \frac{4}{n^4 R^4} \mathbb{E} \left( |B_{n+1}|^4 \right) \\ &\leq \frac{24}{n^2 R^4} \end{align*}$$

for any fixed $R>0$. Applying the Borel-Cantelli lemma we find

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{n \leq t \leq n+1} \left| \frac{B_t}{t} \right| \geq R \, \, \text{for infinitely many $n$} \right) = 0$$

implying

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \limsup_{t \to \infty} \left| \frac{B_t}{t} \right| \leq R \right) = 1.$$

---

Since $R>0$ is arbitrary, the above Lemma implies that

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \lim_{t \to \infty} \left| \frac{B_t}{t} \right| = 0 \right) = 1.$$

For the reflected Brownian motion $W_t := t B_{1/t}$ this means that

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \lim_{t \to 0} |W_t| = 0 \right) = 1.$$

**Remark:** The Lemma shows, in particular, that $\sup_{t \geq 1} |B_t/t| < \infty$ almost surely. This, in turn, implies that

$$\sup_{s \in (0,t)} |W_s| < \infty$$

almost surely for any $t>0$. Using that the mapping $[1,\infty) \ni t \mapsto t B(1/t)$ is continuous, it is not difficult to see that

$$\sup_{s \in (0,t)} |W_s| = \sup_{s \in (0,t) \cap \mathbb{Q}} |W_s|.$$

Therefore

$$\lim_{t \to 0} |W_t| = 0$$

is equivalent to

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \sup_{s \in (0,t) \cap \mathbb{Q}} |W_s| = 0,$$

i.e.

$$\forall n \geq 1 \, \, \exists m \geq 1 \, \, \forall s \in (0,1/m) \cap \mathbb{Q}: \, \, |W_s| \leq \frac{1}{n}.$$